# Which word did people use before "interessant" got borrowed from French?

Tags: etymology, history

The etymology of the word "interessant" seems to be that it was borrowed from the French word "intéressant" - at least that is what [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interessant#Etymology_3) claims.

Which word was used before this word was borrowed? I think that "bemerkenswert" or "beachtenswert" seem to be good candidates although in my feeling these words have a slightly different meaning nowadays.

In particular, I would be interested in a corresponding verb for phrases like "Ich interessiere mich für ...".

Comment: Such einfach Synonyme zu "interessant". Die, die germanischer Ursprung sind, wurden bestimmt auch früher benutzt, um diese Eigenschaft zu beschreiben. Feine Unterschiede in der Bedeutung der Synonyme waren aber vermutlich auch früher relevant für die Entscheidung welches Wort zu verwenden ist. Ich glaube nicht, dass es auf deine Frage nur eine Antwort gibt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a tricky question, because *interessant* has gained further meaning in the last ~200 years.

So let's take a look into history and the word's origin via the [Grimmsche Deutsche Wörterbuch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsches_W%C3%B6rterbuch). It says

> [interessant](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GI00628#XGI00628), nach interesse, vornehmlich in der bedeutung 6 gebildet: ein interessantes buch; das mädchen ist eine recht interessante erscheinung; mir war es interessant, diese nachricht zu erfahren; interessante situationen. Göthe 18, 138.

refering to section 6 of [Interesse](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GI00627#XGI00627)

> 6) endlich der reiz einer sache, der unsern antheil hervorruft: ists denn ein brief von interesse? Fr. Müller 3, 395; wie sie jedem alter seine reize abborgte, freimüthige unschuld von der kindheit, interesse von der jugend. Leisewitz Jul. v. Tarent 1, 1 s. 13.

Looking at these listings we see the phrase "antheil hervorrufen[sic!]", which maybe already the answer to your question.

> [Antheil](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GA05058#XGA05058) steht nun aber auch häufig für das franz. intérêt, und während jenes antheil portio oft neutral gesetzt wird, ist es in diesem sinne überwiegend männlich, man sagt warmen antheil, den gröszten antheil an etwas nehmen, etwas mit vollem, oder ohne den geringsten antheil hören, lesen;

---

Now let us take a look at *[interessieren](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GI00627#XGI00627)*

> nach interesse 5, interessieren, antheil nehmen an jemand oder etwas.

which refers to section 5 of [Interesse](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GI00627#XGI00627)

> in der gewählteren sprache seit dem vorigen jahrhundert ist interesse der antheil, den wir an einer sache nehmen: interesse wird das wohlgefallen genannt, das wir mit der vorstellung der existenz eines gegenstandes verbinden.

Again and again there is this phrase: *antheil nehmen* written today as *Anteil nehmen*.

---

Another source is the DWDS (Digitales Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache). Looking at the etymology section of [interessant](https://www.dwds.de/wb/interessant) it says:

> interessant Adj. ‘reizvoll, Anteilnahme, Aufmerksamkeit erregend’ (18. Jh.), frz. intéressant

and

> interessieren Vb. ‘Aufmerksamkeit, Anteilnahme erwecken’ (17. Jh.); früher bezeugt ist interessiert Part.adj. ‘auf seinen Vorteil bedacht’ (16. Jh.), ‘aufmerksam, voller Anteilnahme’ (18. Jh.)

So when looking for predecessors of the words interessant/interessieren (in their original meaning) your best chances are what the dwds says

> reizvoll, Anteilnahme, Aufmerksamkeit erregend
>
> aufmerksam, voller Anteilnahme

or Grimms

> Anteil nehmen

But ... unfortunately phrases like *Anteilnahme/Anteil nehmen* may have a slightly [different meaning today](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Anteil) ^^ .

Answer (score 5):

Einer der Vorläufer von *interessant* ist dicht am vorgeschlagenen *bemerkenswert*: *merkwürdig*, in der Bedeutung dieses Beispiels aus dem Brockhaus von 1894.

> Historisch merkwürdig ist E. durch die Emser Punktation...

*Interessieren* ist einfacher: *möchte [gerne] wissen*

Answer (score 1):

Based on reading books written in the 1860s etc, the first thing that comes to my mind is

> beachtlich

but of course not in today's most common meaning of "pretty large" but in its primary meaning "noteworthy".

In certain contexts also

> hervorragend

may have been used.